# Ctrl-M chars when transfer files SFTP

Tags: sftp

I am sending files from a windows system to a Unix SFTP server using JSCAPE ftp client.
However, I am experiencing the following issue:
When uploading a text file from windows to UNiX, each line of text files transferred contains Control-M characters. I did some search and found out that If I use the "ASCII" transfer mode it should solve the issue. But the Ctrl-M is still appearing on the files.

Can anyone throw some light in this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure setting the ASCII transfer mode? Are you using the API, you need to turn off auto detect.

Answer (score 2):

**FTP** supports switching between Binary and ASCII transfer mode and converting data on the fly but **SFTP** does not support that feature and it always transfers files unchanged (at least for the most popular version 3 of the protocol).

The utility [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) can be used to convert files from DOS to Unix.

Answer (score 0):

That's the newline character from windows files showing up on UNIX system.

Convert the line endings prior to uploading or find a different FTP server package that can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some text editors have this functionality built in.  For instance, Notepad++

Do you have cygwin? You can use the dos2unix utility.